# Why GraphDB does not allow period in RDF subject name?

Tags: graphdb

Why GraphDB does not load RDF triples which the subject name including a period like Inch_0.0625? I try to load RDF data in Turtle format and prefix is properly defined and attached before the name.The error message like:

RDF Parse Error: Illegal predicate value: ".0625"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal [line 15]

Thanks,
Zhimin Lin

Answer (score 1):

Without your exact file it's difficult to know what happened but it looks like you tried to use a literal value (".0625") as a predicate. All RDF-based databases (including GraphDB) disallow literals in the predicate position.